# Как создать тег внутри тега через событие onload или еще как то

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div id="video" onload=""></div>
```

Нужно чтобы динамически создался iframe внутри тега, как пример ниже

```
<div id="video" onload="">
  <iframe width="390" height="324" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вас самый короткий способ вставить кусок разметки, но так редко поступают:

```
const iframeStr = '<iframe width="390" height="324" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
const videoElem = document.getElementById('video');

const renderIframe = () => {
    videoElem.innerHTML = iframeStr;
};

window.onload = renderIframe;
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно ли я вас понял, но есть несколько вариантов, покажу самый простой:

В html-файле оставляем див, подключаем js файл, и в нём пишем:

```js
const iframe = `<iframe width="390" height="324" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>`;

const video = document.getElementById("video");

video.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', iframe);
```

Быстро поясню что делает весь этот код. Сначала мы в переменную записываем html код, который вставится куда нам нужно, в переменной video мы ищём элемент с айди "video", после чего в insertAdjacentHtml добавляем iframe в основной код. Собственно, один из простых способов создать тег.

Также оставлю ссылки на документацию, [измение документа](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document), [более подробно про insertAdjacentHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)